# Using id <delegate> as a property or parameter to a function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I'm not sure how this works.  I briefly looked at a coworker's C# (I'm not a .NET developer), and I see a lot of stuff that gets passed into methods would be some class object that conforms to an interface.  Is this something that is good to do in objective-c as well?

For example, I'm messing around with the MapKit API and I created my own class that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol so I can have custom views and some extra properties for  the typical pin that gets dropped on the map.  I plan on using this class I created,

```
Address : NSObject
```

as opposed to the MKPlacemark class when I place pins on the map.  In my other view controllers and model classes, do I do:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MKAnnotation> object; //1
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Address *object; //2
```

I started with the example 1, but then when I actually needed some of the properties of the Address object, I found myself having to typecast the object anyway which seemed like what's the point, or I'm missing the point?  So I guess my end question is, is 1 or 2 better, and in what scenarios?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with option 3 which would look like this:

```
Address : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
```

Then when you implement the class, implement the methods required to conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

This way you can have the best of both worlds.

Protocols are very similar to interfaces in languages such as C# or Java. One of the main differences is the ability to require certain methods and have other methods be optional. Since Objective-C is such a dynamic language, you'll see a number of calls such as `[foo responseToSelector:@selector(someSelector:)]`.  If `-someSelector:` was marked as optional, you would need to check to see if the receiver "responds" to that message. If it were marked as required, however, the compile would throw up a warning if you didn't implement that method. Take a look at the [Objective-C Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html) for more information

Comment: I do do that for the object, but then when it comes to using a property or an object that conforms to the <MKAnnotation> protocol, I don't know how to get access to the class since the properties of my Address class are not recognized, unless I typecast the class to the Address object.  Thanks.

Comment: If that is the case, declare your Address object to conform to the protocol and use the Address object as you would normally use it. Does that make sense?

Comment: And to further explain why one would be used over the other:  When using something like MapKit, the API designers declare certain protocols to create a contract for objects to conform to. The API doesn't care what type of object is passed in as long as it conforms to that particular protocol. In your case, you appear to be passing Address objects around as model objects. That is perfectly OK until you need something more generic. Then you could extend the protocol or come up with an inheritance model depending upon your needs. Simpler is better 98% of the time though.

Comment: The part I still don't grasp is, if I use Option 3, and let's say I want to iterate through some array of <MKannotation> objects, then I would do: `for (id <MKAnnotation> obj in array) {  [obj ????] }`  I wouldn't have access to the properties unless I either cast the `obj`, or use `if ([obj respondsToSelector@selector(someMethod:)]) {[obj someMethod]}` right?

Comment: You can also ask the object if it is an instance of a certain class. You can do that by this: `[obj isKindOfClass:[Address class]]`. Objective-C is like any other object oriented language with polymorphism and inheritance. If you don't need to work with MKAnnotations, then work with Address instances. In this case, they are the same thing. MapKit only cares if it conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, your application only cares if it is an instance of `Address`. Pick the approach that best suits your application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use strong keyword for id type, use this instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) id<MyDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: You can absolutely mark an object typed as `id` as retain or strong. The problem you'd run into is having a retain cycle if such a relationship existed. Crystal doesn't appear to be using delegation here so having a strong or retain type of property is perfectly valid.

Comment: But it is advised not to use strong / retain for delegates. So why to take a risk of creating it as strong, even though it isn't used anywhere else and develop knows there are no retain-cycle ?